# Can't edit style.css in subdirectory of my theme?

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, css

I want to edit a file `style.css` but the theme editor shows this:

```
/* ---------- Reset Tags ----------- */
@import url("css/reset.css");

/* ---------- Reset Tags ----------- */
@import url("css/prettyPhoto.css");

/* ---------- Shortcodes ----------- */
@import url("css/shortcodes.css");

/* ---------- Site Styles ---------- */
@import url("css/style.css");
```

Is there any way to edit `css/style.css` via the Theme Editor?

Answer (score 2):

The theme editor [has support for files in a subdirectory](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4131) - but only if this is the main theme and only for PHP files. This seems to be an omission, I [opened a ticket for it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17333).

Answer (score 1):

If you move your CSS files to the root of your theme, instead of a separate "css" directory, the CSS files will show up in the admin automatically.

Comment: no way otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: no, it is not possible to edit a css file which is in a subdirectory of your theme. I would suggest you move the css files to the root of your theme as [Geert](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4936/geert) suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/cant-edit-style-css-in-subdirectory-of-my-theme/16417#16417). You will need to access your site directory via FTP. If you don't know how to do this, contact your hosting provider and they will be able to give you instructions.