# add different stylesheet file to edit themes file list

Tags: dashboard

I am not sure if the title makes sense so feel free to suggest a different one. Anyways…

In Wordpress dashboard *Appearance -> Editor* page I would like to load *app.css* file located in current theme's *assets/css/* directory.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/cant-edit-style-css-in-subdirectory-of-my-theme).

> The theme editor [has support for files in a subdirectory](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4131) - but only if
>   this is the main theme and only for PHP files. This seems to be an
>   omission, I [opened a ticket for it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17333).

Comment: yeah, why would they do that? weirdos

Comment: There is an open ticket to add edit abilities for other files.  Lets hope they honour it.